# What is the SQL equivalent of CallableStatement?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc, callable-statement

I have some code I'm trying to fix and a function is used within a `CallableStatement` but it seems that said function is called in a particular instance where a Schema of the Database becomes the entire 'see-able' database for the function.

Let me explain :

My database (in PostgreSQL) has multiple projects (schemas) such as `i2b2test_project` or `i2b2test_project2`. Each of these projects has an architecture of multiple tables, such as `visit_dimension`, `patient_dimension`, etc..

Now, if I want to reference the `visit_dimension` table from a `i2b2test_project`, I need to use `i2b2test_project.visit_dimension`, as any logical SQL syntax would suggest.

The problem is that, in the code (which I'll include below), a `CallableStatement` is used to execute a function (plain old load-table-from-temp-table function). This function references the architecture mentioned above as if only one project exists, as the database. In other words, instead of referencing `i2b2test_project.visit_dimension`, it only references `visit_dimension`.

I haven't found a way to execute a function in some sort of 'separated instance' of the database and as a result, the function can not be used in a plain SQL statement inside a DB terminal, errors such as `visit_dimension table does not exist` etc..

So I ask : Does the call statement (which indeed seems to reference the schema) allow for such a 'separated instance' of the database ? And is there a way to do so with a plain SQL statement ?

Code :

```
CallableStatement callStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call "
                + this.getDbSchemaName()
                + "INSERT_ENCOUNTERVISIT_FROMTEMP(?,?,?)}");
        callStmt.setString(1, tempTableName);
        callStmt.setInt(2, uploadId);
        callStmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        callStmt.execute();
```

Comment: Including a schema name when it's not strictly necessary shouldn't cause any problems with your queries - so why not just always include the schema name in front of every table/procedure/function?

Comment: I'm not the one who wrote the code. Also, since a good number of parts of said code call for that function, I'd rather not modify the whole thing, or the Function they're calling. There is still the question of how to call a function in a 'separated instance' though

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to ask. Either use dynamic SQL (which is bad), or define the function in each schema, and call it on the appropriate schame. As a side note, the code shown is trying to call "`<schema>INSERT_ENCOUNTERVISIT_FROMTEMP`" and not "`<schema>.INSERT_ENCOUNTERVISIT_FROMTEMP`"

Comment: No, actually, `getDbSchemaName()` sends back the name with a '`.`' at the end. The function is defined in the entire Database. Or is it possible to declare a function in a particular schema, and have it unaccessible to the others?